# Adoptable Storage on LG Stylo2

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, partitions, adoptable-storage

I recently bought a 64GB SD card. Soon discovered adoptable storage is disabled on Stylo2, so I can't change app storage from Internal storage to SD card.
I followed instructions on another forum of how to enable adoptable storage on my phone using ADB commands.
It worked.
But now, my "Storage & USB" Settings shows both Internal Storage and SD card, but File Manager only shows Internal Storage.
And instead of having 16GB internal and 64GB external, File Manger is only showing 10GB TOTAL!!!
It seems like it was partitioned incorrectly.
Is there any way I can fix this?
I'm including a pic of some screenshots of the problem, and the code I used. I really hope you can help!

Correction: I've been exhausted, so I thought maybe I missed something. I looked back over the code from the other forum and over the code I entered. I missed line 3, so I  went back and entered the code, but the problem remains. The code is as follows:

sm set-force-adoptable true

sm partition disk:179,64 private

sm set-force-adoptable false

sm list-volumes all

Would be nice to partition 8GB or so to adopted storage, the ramaining 56GB of the 64GB SD card to "portable"/external storage.

I will probably see e-mail replies before I see them here..
blakburner at gmail dot com

[image]

Comment: I removed your email address based on [Can I give out my e-mail here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23351/can-i-give-out-my-e-mail-here) and [Would that be okay to put up an email address for more help?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/would-that-be-okay-to-put-up-an-email-address-for-more-help)

Comment: For the disk were did you get the 179,64 numbers from? Reasoning devices can be different and there are some commands missing from your list. One being the command that gives you the partition disk numbers. The command `adb shell sm list-disks` which will give your devices partition disk numbers.  Yes, you can delegate a percentage of the sdcard for internal then the rest with something else. You use mixed and desired percentage of space you want seperate instead of private at the end of the am disk:179,64 private. Example: `sm partition disk:179:160 mixed 65`

Comment: I should add the flow of the commands to set adoptable storage:

`adb shell`

`sm list-disks`
(This returns disk id numbers {xxx,xxx or xxx_xxx} which you input into the partition command) 

`sm list-volumes all`

`sm set-force-adoptable true`

`sm partition disk:xxx,xxx` or xxx_xxx

`sm set-force-adoptable false`

`sm list-volumes all`

**important reboot device**

Once rebooted go to Settings --> Storage & USB and tap your SD card. Tap the three dots in the upper-right hand corner and then choose `Migrate data`.

Are these the command and order/sequence  you followed??

Comment: 179,64 was what was in his code that i copied. Sorry though, I've been outta tech stuff for a while, but im not totally unfamiliar from my younger days, so I'm having to adapt to adb commands and terminology. That being said, what is the difference between 'mixed' and 'private'. Have my thoughts, but be better if i just let you clarify.     The other forum didnt include the cmd sm list-disks, nor did it mention Migrate data.

Comment: Be nice if I could put a few returns to separate the lines in my comments, but every time I press enter, it hits the blue Add Comment button instead of doing a line return. Guess I can't separate anything correctly lol. Guess I need to brush up on my code to manually enter. [P] or <P> perhaps lol. I even copied and pasted from notepad app, which had line returns..still none here smh

Comment: And just for curiousity, if my goal is to enable adoptable storage, which is what the code you've given does, and partitions the SD card, then why the "sm set-force-adoptable false" code? Seems like that would do the opposite.

Comment: Update: mixed vs private..i found the answer to that. Question though. Let's say I have 16GB internal storage and 64GB on SD card. Im wanting to partition 24GB of the SD for internal/adopted and leave the remaining 40gb as public/portable for music, etc. By selecting Migrate Data to SD card, I'm setting primary/emulated storage to the partition of the SD instead of my actual Internal Storage. Instead, can I simply partition the SD as mixed so that 24gb is private(adopted/internal) and not choose Migrate Data, so that my actual Internal Storage remains primary? Which would leave me with 40gb...

Comment: ...Which would leave me with 40gb total internal storage (16gb actual internal + 24gb adopted) and 40gb public/external storage.

Comment: So, I entered the code you suggested, but I did not choose Migrate Data yet. Waiting for your response.
Results:
SETTINGS>STORAGE & USB>Device Storage:
-Internal Storage (16GB), SD Card (~40GB), SD Card (Not Inserted)
>Portable Storage:
-SD Card (22GB)
FILE MANAGER:
Internal Storage (10GB)!!!???
SD Card (22GB)
I have screen shots that make a little more sense.
Pretty much though, according to Storage & USB, I have a combined total of ~52GB Internal (was only wanting 40), and 22GB external (was also wanting 40).
But File Mgr only shows 10GB Internal! & 22GB external.

Comment: Update:
I after re-partitioning the SD card and having the incorrect percentages, I re-partitioned again.
Now I have under Device Storage: 16gb Internal, 22.23gb SD (adopted), and 2 other SD cards ("not inserted"). And under Portable Storage I have 36.86gb SD card (which would be the external partition ofcourse. A lot closer to the numbers I was wanting. Any idea what's up with the 2 extra "not inserted" SD cards?
Is it from the 2 previous partitions? I would assume those partitions were mounted, and now they're not there, but the mount point is? If so, should I unmount them?